# How do I change the caption of the "Login" button?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen

When setting up a user for login without a password (i.e., by adding the user to the nopasswdlogin group), a "Login" button appears in the LightDM screen.

How do I change the caption on the login button, e.g. to "Enter" or "Start"?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Comment: It seems this message (the "Login" sign on the greeter screen) is defined here: `/usr/share/locale-langpack/da/LC_MESSAGES/unity-greeter.mo`

It's possible to patch this file manually, which may be what we choose to do in the first iteration, especially if care is taken to retain the same field length. However, we really should find a way to patch this from the source translation files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just not to let this go unanswered: The correct solution would be to provide a custom translation to the "unity-greeter" language file and replace each locale's rendition of "Login" with the same locale's rendition of "Start" for the login button text.

I did not do that, however, and frankly I don't know how to do it either. Instead, I actually ended up patching `/usr/share/locale-langpack/da/LC_MESSAGES/unity-greeter.mo`. This is a not 100% satisfactory hack, but it did work and bring me onwards, and it did get the users a "Start" rather than "Login" button.

It conceivably might be easier/more obvious to find out how to customize these GUI texts.